# SQL Spatial Feature export

Tags: export, sql-server-spatial

I managed to successfully import the spatial features from the MSSQL into QGIS and would like to know if the following is possible and how would I go about doing it:

Edit the attributes (without first saving it as a shapefile) in order to make changes to the database, and
Reproject the SQL spatial features and export back into the database.

Comment: What do you mean by `import the spatial features from the MSSQL into QGIS`? Did you connect to SQL Server from QGIS and can see the spatial tables there? Also, please explain how do you want to `Edit the attributes`.

Comment: Hi, yes I connected to the SQL Server from QGIS and added the features, but I can't edit them unless I save it as a shapefile. I would like to edit the attribute table information so that it is changed in the database. Is it possible to do this? Does it make sense?